# react | redux-form | material-ui | how to combine DatePicker with my form

Tags: reactjs, datepicker, redux, material-ui, redux-form

After solving some problems, I stuck with sending DatePicker data to my form. In my form I use mostly elements from redux-form-material-ui, but DatePicker is not a part of it.

I found 2 ways of creating DatePicker component with redux-form.

```
<Field
  name="startDate"
  autoOk={true}
  floatingLabelText="startDate"
  component={(startDate) => {
    return <DatePicker {...startDate} />;
  }}
  onChange={(event, date) => {console.log(date);}}
/>
```

and

```
<DatePicker
  name="startDate"
  autoOk={true}
  floatingLabelText="startDate"
  onChange={(event, date) => {console.log(date)}} />
```

The problem is that I don't know the way to update the form data with it. The first example even doesn't show the picked date in text field. I can see in `form.myForm` store, that I made date field active, but it is never updated with picked date. The second shows picked date, but it is not a part of `form.myForm` object...

I found some examples in internet (e.g. https://github.com/erikras/redux-form/issues/364 ) but there is no `fields` object in props, so cannot call `this.props.fields.startDate.onChange`.

I'm not sure what is a good way of working with redux-form and material-ui, as there is not many working examples. I started to think of making a wrapper to EVERY component I use, which will provide onChange method, which will update my store with any change made in form. But then I don't need redux-form anymore, so I think there must some other solution, I could use.

```
"react": "15.1.0",
"react-tap-event-plugin": "1.0.0",
"redux": "3.0.5",
"redux-form": "^6.0.0-alpha.4",
"redux-form-material-ui": "^2.0.0",
```

Comment: the new version of redux-form-material-ui does have date picker, with the current realise the time picker is not functional.

Answer (score 5):

```
import React from 'react';
import DatePicker from 'material-ui/DatePicker';

export default ({ input, label, meta: { touched, error }, ...custom }) => {
    return (
        <DatePicker
          onChange={(e, val) => {return input.onChange(val)}}
          {...custom}
          value={input.value}
        />
);
}
```

Considering this as in file `renderDatePicker.js`, usage would be,

```
<Field name="created_on" component={RenderDatePicker} floatingLabelText="Created Date"/>
```

Where `Field` is imported from `redux-form`.
Remember to provide `{created_on: new Date('someiso8601')}` in `this.props.initialize` to autopopulate it.

Comment: can you elaberate on `this.props.initialize`? It's really taking so much time to make datetime work with redux-form..

Comment: @eugene, please refer http://www.davidmeents.com/create-redux-form-validation-initialized-values/ [was bit busy, sorry :)]

Comment: just for the record, you don't need to use the keyword `return` if your callback is just one line, it will return by itself so you can remove the `return` keyword as well as the `{}`, or wrap the line in `()`

Answer (score 3):

I used react-datepicker with redux form. The key was to set "selected" property correctly.

```
const selectedDate = this.props.fields.date.value ?
  moment(this.props.fields.date.value, 'DD/MM/YYYY') :
  moment();

<DatePicker
  {...date}
  className="form-control"
  dateFormat="DD/MM/YYYY"
  selected={selectedDate}
/>
```

Answer (score 2):

Here is how I use it in my code.

```
<DatePicker
    selected={dateField.value}
    onChange={param => dateField.onChange(param)} />
```

`dateField` simply comes from:

```
const {fields: {dateField}, handleSubmit} = this.props;
```

Comment: As I wrote I cannot see `fields` property in my form

Answer (score 1):

Not just for this Datepicker but for any custom input, create a separate component to manage the input type and process. Which makes easy to feed your redux-form fields. This is the simple process I was taught by my senior developers when I was a Grad.

In your case, firstly import following additional libraries to your redux-form component

```
import moment from 'moment'
import { change } from 'redux-form'  //We use the change to dispatch the own props of the redux-form component to resetDateField
```

Create a separate component by importing DatePicker in it. And your component will look something like this:

```
const datePickerInput = ({input,name,label,...props}) => {
 return (
  <div>
   <label htmlFor={input.name}> 
    <span>
     {label}
    </span> 
   </label>
   <div>
      <DatePicker
          className='form-control'
          {...input}
          {...props}
      />
   </div>
  </div>
 )
}
```

Now feed this component to your redux-form field's component.

```
<Field
  name = "startDate"
  label = "Start Date"
  dateFormat = 'MMM Do YY'
  component={datePickerInput}
  selected = {/*pass state value of startDate or pass some default null for startDate if nothing selected*/}
  onChange={ (date) => {this.handleChangeStartDate(date, 'startDate')} } //bind this function in constructor and also setState value for your start date as null or some default 
/>
```

the onChange function is to be handled something like this using moment:

```
handleChangeStartDate(date, target) {
    const {resetDateField } = this.props
    this.setState({
      [target]: moment(date)
    })
    resetDateField('startDate', '' )
  }
```

Now hook this resetDateField in your reduxForm @connect by passing dispatch and ownProps and returning resetDateField value expecting a dispatch of change for current form, field, and field value that you want to change using this resetDateField.